# Como atualizar uma UIWebView para incluir e remover um UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, swift

Estou com dificuldade para incluir e finalizar a exibição de um UIActivityIndicatorView ("animação de carregamento"). Já tentei utilizar webViewDidStartLoad e webViewDidFinishLoad, respectivamente para iniciar e finalizar a animação, porém, não tive sucesso. O código que estou utilizando é esse:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var visaoWeb: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var carregamento: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    let urlString : String = "http://www.google.com.br"

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        if let url = NSURL(string: self.urlString) {
            let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            self.visaoWeb.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest)
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        self.carregamento.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        self.carregamento.stopAnimating()
    }
     */

}
```

Obs: Estou utilizando swift 3.0

Comment: o correto Swift 3 seria `if let url = URL(string: urlString) { visaoWeb.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url)) }`

Comment: Obrigado @LeoDabus, agora sim sinto que o código tá evoluindo aos poucos. Uma dúvida, seria adequado utilizar self.variavel para fazer referência a variáveis da própria classe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está no caminho certo Fábio. Tem algumas coisas que podem estar impedindo seu código de funcionar corretamente.

1. Para os métodos do delegate de UIWebView serem chamados é necessário passar pra a webView qual objeto será seu delegate, no caso self. Você pode fazer isso pelo nib ou no código (self.visaoWeb.delegate = self)
2. O código acessa uma url com protocol http. Por padrão o App Transport Security vai bloquear esse tipo de conexão. Use https ou [adicione uma excessão para permitir o acesso por http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http).
3. Verifique no Storyboard se a conexão para os outlets está correta (visaoWeb e carregamento)
4. Use a assinatura correta do método *webViewDidFinishLoad*

   ```
   func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

     self.carregamento.stopAnimating()
     self.carregamento.removeFromSuperview()
   }
   ```

Comment: Obrigado. Tive que adicionar a referência (self.visaoWeb.delegate = self) e corrigir a assinatura webViewDidFinishLoad. O restante estava correto.